# Can anyone help me to get the number of counts in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to count the number of "tlikers" in each different "tlid"**

```
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55d8a835363ffb2157589145"),
            "like" : [
                {
                    "tlid" : 111,
                    "tlikers" : [
                        "amudibarongo@gmail.com",
                        "harunabarongo@gmail.com"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tlid" : 112,
                    "tlikers" : [
                        "amudibarongo@gmail.com",
                        "harunabarongo@gmail.com"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tlid" : 113,
                    "tlikers" : [
                        "amudibarongo@gmail.com",
                        "harunabarongo@gmail.com",
                        "jumabarongo@gmial.com"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "tlikeid" : "amudibarongo@gmail.com"
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregation query for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$like"},
    {$project: {"tlid": "$like.tlid", "count": {$size: "$like.tlikers"}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", "likes": {$push: {tlid: "$tlid", count : "$count"}}}}
])
```

This will produce a result like:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55d8a835363ffb2157589145"),
        "likes" : [ 
            {
                "tlid" : 111,
                "count" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "tlid" : 112,
                "count" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "tlid" : 113,
                "count" : 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the below written python script will get you the desired output:

(Let's say the collection name is :"sample")

```
data = sample.find()
for doc in data:
    NumberOfEntries = len(doc['like'])
    for i in range(0,NumberOfEntries):
        print "tlid : ",doc['like'][i]['tlid'], "Count of tlikers:",len(doc['like'][i]['tlikers'])
```

Rather than printing on console, You can also store these values in a dictionary for further use.